# How to align html elements on the same row

Tags: html, css

If you see the attachment below, three share buttons are not equally margined from the top. Tweet button didn't maintain the consistency, it is little bit up than the other two. How do I make all of them equally distanced from the top?

[image]

The code I am working on:

```
                            <h2 class="title">Share this blog</h2>

                            <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://alfa-blog.com/"
                                 data-layout="button_count" data-size="large" data-mobile-iframe="true">
                                <a class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore" target="_blank" 
                                   href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Falfa-blog.com%2Findex.html&amp;src=sdkpreparse">Share</a>
                            </div>

                            <a href="https://twitter.com/share" 
                               data-size="large"
                               class="twitter-share-button" data-show-count="false">Tweet</a>

                            <div class="g-plus" data-action="share" data-height="24" data-href="http://alfa-blog.com/"></div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

using flex-box it can be done like this

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://alfa-blog.com/"
      data-layout="button_count" data-size="large" data-mobile-iframe="true">
      <a class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore" target="_blank" 
         href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Falfa-blog.com%2Findex.html&amp;src=sdkpreparse">Share</a>
   </div>
   <a href="https://twitter.com/share" 
      data-size="large"
      class="twitter-share-button" data-show-count="false">Tweet</a>
   <div class="g-plus" data-action="share" data-height="24" data-href="http://alfa-blog.com/"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: flex-start
    }
```

this is a really good guide
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Hi thanks. it works. Actually, I have never come up with flex-direction property before. I will check that complete guide as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since your css is missing I will assume that you use `display:inline-block;`, you probably forgot to include :

```
.your_icons {
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`float:left;` and individual margin and padding in css for each socio div

or absolute position for these elements

Answer (score 0):

It may work for you..

```css
.social-holder {width: 100%;}
.social-holder * {display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;}
```

```html
<h2 class="title">Share this blog</h2>
<div class="social-holder">
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://alfa-blog.com/"
data-layout="button_count" data-size="large" data-mobile-iframe="true">
<a class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore" target="_blank" 
href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Falfa-blog.com%2Findex.html&amp;src=sdkpreparse">Share</a>
</div>

<a href="https://twitter.com/share" 
data-size="large"
class="twitter-share-button" data-show-count="false">Tweet</a>

<div class="g-plus" data-action="share" data-height="24" data-href="http://alfa-blog.com/"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the respective button codes inside a `div` element which functions as a *mask*. Like so:

```
<h2 class="title">Share this blog</h2>

<div class="socialbtn socialbtn-facebook">
  <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://alfa-blog.com/" data-layout="button_count" data-size="large" data-mobile-iframe="true">
    <a class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore" target="_blank" href="[address]">Share</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="socialbtn socialbtn-twitter">
  <a href="https://twitter.com/share" data-size="large" class="twitter-share-button" data-show-count="false">Tweet</a>
</div>

<div class="socialbtn socialbtn-googlePlus">
  <div class="g-plus" data-action="share" data-height="24" data-href="http://alfa-blog.com/"></div>
</div>
```

with the CSS code:

```
.socialbtn {display:inline-flex;height:25px;width:auto;overflow-y:hidden}
.socialbtn-googlePlus {margin-top:-10px}
.socialbtn-twitter {margin-top:0px}
.socialbtn-facebook {margin-top:-5px}
```

Please correct the respective margins to rectify your situation.